# Autofilter combine text and color vba

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

Is it possible to use Autofilter to sort data based on both value and interior 
color?

Something like this:

```
Range("D3:D300").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("NOK", "="), _
Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria2:= RGB(255,0,0), _
Operator:=xlFilterCellColor, VisibleDropDown:=False
```

Comment: If the color criteria and value criteria are not in the same column, yes, it is possible. Record a macro and you'll see it. Adapt the code to your needs.

Comment: Okej, so its not possible to if they are in the same column? I did use an IF-statement to filter before, but it takes much longer to loop through all rows compared to use the autofilter.

Comment: Nope, it's not. You can apply only 1 criteria per field (at least in Excel 2007, don't know in higher versions). Imagine you have a column with data colored in 3 colors (red, yellow, no color). You can filter data by 1 single color. Here's is the same. You could apply a criteria in 1 column based on a single color, and then filter the results by a second criteria IN ANOTHER COLUMN. This second criteria could be also a color type criteria, but applied in a different column. To resume, 1 criteria per column (criteria can be color, values, between dates, and so on, but just 1 single criteria)

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns just fyi, this also applies to newer versions.

Comment: @RawrplusThanks for the info. I'm so used to Excel 2007 that I must admit I have never bothered in looking into the new functionalities of higher versions.

Comment: @Olivia Perhaps you should reconsider the question though. While it is not possible to apply multiple filters to a single column, it is possible to loop over the data and apply multiple `if` conditions (and re-create a new table with the matching data)

Comment: Thank you both for fast replies! I'll rearrange the data in new columns so I can use the filters after

Comment: Good to know. I'll use my previous comment as answer then.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, it's not. You can apply only 1 criteria per field. Imagine you have a column with data colored in 3 colors (red, yellow, no color). You can filter data by 1 single color. Here's is the same. You could apply a criteria in 1 column based on a single color, and then filter the results by a second criteria IN ANOTHER COLUMN. This second criteria could be also a color type criteria, but applied in a different column.

> To resume, 1 criteria per column (criteria can be color, values,
>   between dates, and so on, but just 1 single criteria)